# How to import an external javascript library in angular?

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I'm trying to import libraries like popper, jquery and chart.js to use in an angular project.

I've downloaded them using the cli, referenced them in my `index.html` and in `angular.json` file.

`index.html`

```
<head>
...
<script src="node_modules/chart.js/dist/Chart.js"></script>
</head>
```

```
angular.json
```

```
...
"styles": [
              "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css",
              "node_modules/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css",
              "src/styles.css"
            ],
            "scripts": [
              "node_modules/chart.js/dist/Chart.js"
            ]
...
```

The error message that appears is

```
The resource from “http://localhost:4200/node_modules/chart.js/dist/Chart.js” was blocked due to MIME type (“text/html”) mismatch (X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff)
```

Comment: If you have correctly installed via CLI, then you don't need to manually change index.html or angular.json. Include the package in your app.module.ts, or if it is just a script, you can import from the TS file you're using it in..

Comment: if it is a NPM module then you do not need to import in scripts. Use ES6 way in any of the component.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Taking Chart.js as an example:

```
npm install --save chart.js
npm install --save-dev @types/chart.js
```

Then in your component:

```
import * as Chart from 'chart.js'

...

const chart = new Chart(...)
```

No need to touch `index.html` or put anything in your `angular.json` scripts.